# Applets - Can't get parameters from param using <object>

Tags: java, html, object, applet

**[Edit]**

Followed Andrew Thompson's advice and wrote a script. However, I still can't make the app work. It does look like parameters is wrong.

```
<![CDATA[
var attributes =
{
   code: 'site.SiteSelector', 
   archive: '../src/site/site.jar', 
   width: 280, 
   height: 280
};
var parameters = {title0: 'Java Home Page', location0: 'http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/', 
title1: 'Deitel', location1: 'http://www.deitel.com/', title2: 'JGuru', location2: 'http://www.guru.com/'
, title3: 'JavaWorld', location3: 'http://www.javaworld.com/'};
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
 ]]>
```

**[/Edit]**

I'm trying to get values from `<param>` from the html5 written. The problem is that every time, I receive null as the return value from `getParameter()`. Moreover, I don't know if I wrote object correctly. The program worked with the `<applet>` tag.

```
package site;

import java.applet.AppletContext;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class SiteSelector extends JApplet {

private HashMap<String, URL> sites;
private ArrayList<String> siteNames;
private JList<String> siteChooser;

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Override
public void init() {
    sites = new HashMap<String, URL>();
    siteNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    getSitesFromHTMLParameters();
    add(new JLabel("Choose a site to browse"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    siteChooser = new JList(siteNames.toArray());
    siteChooser.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            URL newDocument = sites.get(siteChooser.getSelectedValue());
            AppletContext browser = getAppletContext();
            browser.showDocument(newDocument);
        }
    });
    add(new JScrollPane(siteChooser), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private void getSitesFromHTMLParameters() {
    String title = null;
    URL location = null;
    int count = 0;

    title = getParameter("title" + count);
    while (title != null) {
        try {
            location = new URL(getParameter("location" + count));
            sites.put(title, location);
            siteNames.add(title);
        } catch (MalformedURLException urlException) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SiteSelector.this, String.format(
                    "Error: %s.Message: %s\n", urlException.getClass()
                            .getName(), urlException.getMessage()),
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        ++count;
        title = getParameter("title" + count);
    }
   }
}
```

### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Site Selector</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <object id="siteselectorapplet-object"
            classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" width="256"
            height="256"                          
       codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6u30-windows-i586.cab#version=1,6,0,0"> 
                <param name="archive" value="../src/site/site.jar">                                
            <param name="code" value="site.SiteSelector">
            <param name="title0" value="Java Home Page">
            <param name="location0"
          value="http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/">
            <param name="title1" value="Deitel">
            <param name="location1" value="http://www.deitel.com/">
            <param name="title2" value="JGuru">
            <param name="location2" value="http://www.guru.com/">
            <param name="title3" value="JavaWorld">
            <param name="location3" value="http://www.javaworld.com/">
          </object>
    </body>
```

Comment: The best way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).